# Cognos 8 Reports- Specify decimal separator for different locales

Tags: cognos-8, cognos-bi

I have a Cognos-8 based report which has several number columns. I have set the decimal separator for these columns explicilty as 
Number
Decimal Places: 2
Decimal Separator: period (.)
Negative number symbol: ()

When I run the report in the English locale, all the columns display the output correctly , for eg: 1.20, 30.33, (3.30)

When I run the report in the French locale, the negative number outputs are displayed with a separator comma(,) instead of period (.). What could be causing this and how can I set the separator to comma in French locale?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

I set the report to the negative conditional variable for each column and then set the separator as period.This fixed it.